# Button Codes for Primefaces' Text Editor

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

Primefaces has two text editors, the deprecated "[editor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml)" and more recent "[text editor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml)".  For the prior I could find the code for specific buttons, but I cannot find any such code for the new one, and disappointingly the old codes don't seem to translate.  For example:

```
controls="bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript 
font size style color highlight bullets numbering alignleft center 
alignright justify link unlink outdent indent"
```

works on the old editor, but only: bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, font, size, link, appear as buttons when added using HTML tags like:

```
<button class="ql-bold"></button>
```

What are the codes for the aforementioned buttons, and also for the remove formatting button?  The documentation provided on the website is out of date.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the list. Either delete or set `style="display: none;"` the button you do not want to show.

```
<p:textEditor
    id="descriptionId"
    widgetVar="descriptionWidget"
    value="#{bean.model.description}">
    <f:facet name="toolbar">
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-font" />
            <select class="ql-size" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-bold" />
            <button class="ql-italic" />
            <button class="ql-underline" />
            <button class="ql-strike" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-color" />
            <select class="ql-background" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-script" value="sub" />
            <button class="ql-script" value="super" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-header" value="1" />
            <button class="ql-header" value="2" />
            <button class="ql-blockquote" />
            <button class="ql-code-block" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-list" value="ordered" />
            <button class="ql-list" value="bullet" />
            <button class="ql-indent" value="-1" />
            <button class="ql-indent" value="+1" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-direction" value="rtl" />
            <select class="ql-align" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-link" />
            <button class="ql-image" />
            <button class="ql-video" />
            <button class="ql-formula" />
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-clean" />
        </span>
    </f:facet>
</p:textEditor>
```

Comment: Great answer, it really helped me.

Comment: Great answer. I'll update the documentation to include them all.